# ARM Assembly Project - Finding a Substring

Tags: string, pointers, assembly, arm, substring

I am working on a project for school to find a substring in an array of charaters. The assembly program is called from c and passes three arguments: the array(a1), the starting index(a2), and the ending index(a3).

The current solution I have is as followed :

```
 .global mysubstring

 mysubstring:
 stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}
 mov v1, a1 @copy array into a register
 mov v2, a2 @copy starting index into a register
 sub a1, a3, a2
 add a1, a1, #1 @finds how many bytes to request from malloc
 bl malloc @call c library routine to create a pointer to allocated space in a1
 loop:
 ldrbt v5, [v1], v2 @load byte located in v1, indexed by v2, into register v5
 strbt a1, [v5] @store byte located in v5 into a1
 add v2, v2, #1 @increment index
 cmp v2, a3 @check if we've reached the end
 ble loop 
 bl printf 
 ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6,pc}
 .end
```

I'll admit that my understanding of assembly is very poor and may have messed up meaning of somethings.

Whenever I run the c program, the assembly program returns (null). I have a feeling it is because I'm not properly adding items into a1 (should I be?). I believe malloc is appropriately designating the required space for my substring, I feel the error is in the loop subroutine.

If anyone could please give me some insight on where to go from here it would be most appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the wrong addressing mode:

```
ldrbt v5, [v1], v2 @load byte located in v1, indexed by v2, into register v5
```

That's the "register post-indexed" mode, which effectively does:

```
address = v1
v1 += v2
v5 = *address
```

Note that `v1` will be modified after each load, since post-increment addressing implicitly writes back the indexed address.

What you want is "register pre-indexed" addressing, which would be written as:

```
ldrbt v5, [v1, v2]
```